# Separate array into multidimensional array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array from a csv with data that I need to parse. The data is as follows:

```
Array
1. PO|115207534
2. OD|115207534
3. PO|115207535
4. OD|115207535
5. OD|115207536
```

I need to separate it into subarrays, with the first entry of each being the PO lines. There could be any number of OD lines, but always only 1 PO. The new array needs to be as follows:

```
Array
1.
PO|115207534
OD|115207534
2.
PO|115207535
OD|115207535
OD|115207536
```

What's the most efficient using only one foreach loop? And using 2 foreach loops?

Comment: Have you tried any thing so far?

Comment: Do we have to do your homework for free ?

Comment: Sorry I know it's a terrible question, I'm just trying to get some order processing set up for a friend and this isn't exactly my trade (as you can tell) so just figured I could get a bit of help as anything I tried, for some reason, limited the subarray to 3 and it would separate any successive OD line after that into it's own array. I would put what I tried but it's a waste of time for you guys to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this to split the imported items as number of chunked arrays by the value **"PO"**,

```
<?php
$array = array("PO", "OD", "PO", "OD", "OD", "OD", "OD", "PO", "OD", "PO", "OD", "OD");
$result = array();
$index = -1;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value == "PO") {
        $index++;
    }
    $result[$index][] = $value;
}
?>
<pre>
    <?php
    print_r($result);
    ?>    
</pre>
```

Output:
http://codepad.org/aXpK43Uw